# Is there a way to buy a Dell dekstop/laptop with pre-installed Ubuntu?

Tags: dell, inspiron

In the near future (probably in the year end sale season), I am going to buy a Dell laptop. Problem is, I am completely pissed off by Microsoft Windows 8, which is almost universally pre-installed in Dell computers. I've heard that there are some desktops/laptops that you can buy from Dell with Ubuntu pre-installed. But, I didn't find such desktop/laptops in Dell official site.

Where is the access point to buy the desktop/laptop from Dell with a pre-installed Ubuntu system? If Ubuntu is not available, could I buy a Dell computer pre-installed with Linux Mint?

Looks like there is a Dell Inspiron 15R (N5110) [equipped with Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201012-6932/) LTS12.04, but I didn't find it in Dell official site, and don't where to place the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can buy Dell laptop with Ubuntu in it but it is expensive ($1300).

http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-linux/pd

I think this is the only model sold by Dell.

May be you should consider vendors like System76, Zareason, Los Alamos computers etc.. if you want to buy a laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed.

Comment: Taken a quick look at its specs, and found it is using Solid State hard drive. No wonder so expensive. And the capacity of the hard drive is only 128GB. Not good enough. Could you give me some other links to cheaper alternatives (still want Ubuntu pre-installed)? Thanks!

Comment: Here is link to System76: https://www.system76.com/laptops/model/gazp9  and Zareason: http://zareason.com/shop/Laptops/ . You can also contact them for refurbished laptops which are usually cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Right on the Dell site, you also can order it from there:

http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/xps-13-linux/pd